# Iteration number when using TestCaseSource

Tags: nunit

Is it possible to get an Iteration number for each test case  when using the TestCaseSource attribute?

for example

```
public static object[][] MyTestCases =
{ 
    new object[] { 1 , 3},  //iteration 1
    new object[] { 7 , 9},  //iteration 2
    new object[] { 3 , 5},  //iteration 3
}
[Test, TestCaseSource(nameof(MyTestCases))]
public void MyTest(int valA, valB){


    Assert.That(result, Is.EqualTo(valB), $"Some reason"); // <---- include the iteration with the message
}
```

I would like to be able to include the iteration number in the assert message.

Comment: What use is the iteration number? Why not just use `valA` and `valB`?

Comment: Iteration number i mean is the index + 1 of the MyTestCases array. So matching the test to the data that is used as the input

I can't use valA/valB Because in more complex cases it's hard to match the variables to the line that it relates to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A College found a solution shortly after when trying to solve the some problem.

It combines TestCaseData with C# 5.0 `CallerLineNumber` attribute.

```
public static MyTestCaseData[] MyTestCases =
{ 
    new MyTestCaseData(1 , 3),  //iteration 1
    new MyTestCaseData(7 , 9),  //iteration 2
    new MyTestCaseData(3 , 5),  //iteration 3
}
[Test, TestCaseSource(nameof(MyTestCases))]
public void MyTest(int valA, valB){


    Assert.That(result, Is.EqualTo(valB), $"Some reason"); // <---- include the iteration with the message
}


public class MyTestCaseData : TestCaseData
{
    public MyTestCaseData(int valA, int valB [CallerLineNumber] int lineNumber = -1) 
        : base(valA, valB)
        {
                SetName($"(#{lineNumber}) - My Test Name");
        }
}
```

As long as you provide the optional parameter `[CallerLineNumber] int lineNumber = -1` it will be initialized with the line number of that relates to the instantiation of the iteration.

Not entirely sure how this work, i would expect this to be some line in the NUnit framework that executes your test.

Answer (score 1):

Two approaches are possible:

1. Include iteration number as an argument to the method.
2. Use `TestCaseData` instances rather than `object[]` for each argument set. `TestCaseData` allows you to specify a name for the test that can include your interation number if you like.

Comment: Both of those methods require you to manually maintain the iteration number don't they?